Laravel Sail up process failed| laravel.test Warning failed to resolve reference
bash ./vendor/bin/sail up
[+] Running 1/1
 ! laravel.test Warning failed to resolve reference "sail-8.4/app:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://sail-8.4/v2/a...

This error appears directly once I write:
bash ./vendor/bin/sail up
I tried docker login and composer update and re-installed Laravel Sail, I also re-installed Docker many times, I am using WSL 2 as the Docker engine with the following JSON configuration:
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "dns": [
    "8.8.8.8",
    "8.8.4.4"
  ],
  "experimental": false
}

Other Docker images, like pgsql, redis and ubuntu successfully build, but my Laravel app with Docker does not.
PS C:\laragon\www\car-monitor> bash ./vendor/bin/sail up
[+] Running 1/1
 ! laravel.test Warning failed to resolve reference "sail-8.4/app:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://sail-8.4/v2/a...

I have tried many solutions but the same result, the problem continues, the build process continues and another error appears:
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
1449.7 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable [+] Running 0/1e to correct problems, you have held broken
packages.  ⠦ Service laravel.test  Building                           
1512.6s  failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y     && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings     && apt-get
install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor
sqlite3

I am using Laravel 11, PHP 8.4, Sail 8.4, and the latest Docker version and Windows 11 operating system.
Can someone help me solving this problem?

You don't need to do bash ./vendor/bin/sail up, you can just use ./vendor/bin/sail up.
Also try rebuilding with ./vendor/bin/sail up --build

Also, did you drop Sail into an existing Laravel application? Because if you did you need to run php artisan sail:install first. Maybe also try ./vendor/bin/build --no-cache and run ./vendor/bin/sail up after.

I already did that (sail install) but the same result, my project is on my local desktop.
